# invalid new-expression of abstract class type error

Tags: c++, sorting

**Homework** 
I'm getting this type of error for my Merge Sort function. I think the error has something to do with my `merge()` method, but I thought I took care of it by using it in `MergeSort()`. Any help would be appreciated.
Sort.h

```
#ifndef SORT_H_
#define SORT_H_

class Sort {
protected:
   unsigned long num_cmps; // number of comparisons performed in sort function
public:
   virtual void sort(int A[], int size)= 0;    // main entry point
   bool testIfSorted(int A[], int size);        // returns false if not sorted
                                            // true otherwise
   unsigned long getNumCmps() { return num_cmps; }        // returns # of comparisons
   void resetNumCmps() { num_cmps = 0; }
};

class MergeSort:public Sort {       // MergeSort class
public:
  void sort(int A[], int size, int low, int high);      // main entry point
};

#endif
```

Sort.cpp

```
 Sort* s;
   switch(op.getAlg()) 
      {
      case 'S':
         s=new SelectionSort();
         break;
      case 'I':
         s=new InsertionSort();
         break;
      case 'B':
         s=new BubbleSort();
         break;
      case 'H':
         s=new HeapSort();
         break;
      case 'R':
         s=new RadixSort();
         radixsortQ = true;
         break;
      case 'M':
         s=new MergeSort(); --> error
         break;
      }
```

Merge Sort.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sort.h"
using namespace std;
void MergeSort::sort(int A[], int size, int low, int high)          // main entry point
{
    if (low < high){
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        MergeSort(A, size, low, middle);
        MergeSort(A, size, middle+1, high);
        merge(A, size, low, middle, high);
    }
}

void merge::sort(int A[], int size, int low, int middle, int high){
    int temp[size];
    for(int i = low; i <= high; i++){
        temp[i] = A[i];
    }
    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;

    while(i <= middle && j <= high){
        if(temp[i] <= temp[j]){
            A[k] = temp[i];
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            A[k] = temp[j];
            ++j;
        }
        ++k;
    }
    while(i <= middle){
        A[k] = temp[i];
        ++k;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually overriding the sort function, so MergeSort is still an abstract class:

```
Sort::sort(int A[], int size)= 0;
MergeSort::sort(int A[], int size, int low, int high);      // main entry point
```

These sorts have different signatures, so they are different functions.

To solve this, you either need to change your MergeSort::sort method to not take in a `low` and `high` argument, or to add a `low` and `high` argument to your other sort methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a virtual class MergeSort because function's sort has a different numbers of parameters

```
virtual void Sort::sort(int A[], int size) = 0;

        void MergeSort::sort(int A[], int size, int low, int high);

 will be error  s=new MergeSort();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sort::sort` needs to be overridden. In order to override a virtual function, you need to declare a function with the same name in a derived class that has the **same parameter types.** If you add extra parameters, you're not overriding the virtual function in the base class anymore. So `MergeSort` is still an abstract class as it has not overridden the pure virtual function in `Sort`.

You'll have to declare `MergeSort::sort` like this:

```
void sort(int A[], int size); // although you can change the parameter names
```

and then have it delegate to another function (which should probably be private) that takes `low` and `high` as parameters.